# What is the minimum amount of toothpicks that must be removed?

Tags: combinatorics

### Thirty identical toothpicks were used to create the figure below. There are over 25 triangles in the figure. What is the fewest number of toothpicks that could be removed so that no triangles remain?

(Note that the triangles don't have to be unit triangles!)

Well, I tried this (apparently quite famous) puzzle and achieved a result of 7, which is incorrect. Can somebody guide me through the thought process here, and how I can solve this problem? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: I think you need at least $10$ toothpicks, perhaps you can start by double checking your solution with $7$ toothpicks.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the $10$ small triangles in the image

[image]

We must remove at least one toothpick from each of them, and since none of them share toothpicks this means we must remove at least $10$ toothpicks.

On the other hand if we remove all $10$ of the horizontal toothpicks we'll only have toothpicks in two different directions remaining, you can't form a triangle with them (as it would have two paralel sides).

So I think the answer is $10$.

Comment: yep, I made a mistake (this is correct)
thanks!

Comment: my pleasure !${}$